# How does one populate a row in pandas python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, append

I have initialised a dataframe in python to simulate a matrix

```
 llist = ["this", "is", "a","sentence"]
 df = pd.DataFrame(columns = llist, index = llist)
```

Now I want to populate a row as follows

```
 test = [1,0,0,0]
 df.iloc[[1]] = test
```

this throws up the following error

> ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different       length than the value

When I set the value as below it populates the row with the same value

```
  test = [1]
  df.iloc[[1]] = test
```

Can someone tell me why this happens and the most efficient way of populating a row with a list of different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need remove one `[]`:

```
test = [1,0,0,0]
df.iloc[1] = test

print (df) 
         this   is    a sentence
this      NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
is          1    0    0        0
a         NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
sentence  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
```